# Does IdentityServer4 still allow ResourceAuthorize?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, identityserver3

I'm looking at upgrading from IdentityServer3 to IdentityServer4, specifically because we're upgrading existing projects from .NET 4.5 to .NET Core 3.1.

The biggest issue I see right now is that we use the ResourceAuthorize attribute to check if the user has permission against a resource

```
[ResourceAuthorize("Read","urn://someresource")]
```

But looking through the ID4 documentation and the code base, it doesn't look like ResourceAuthorize exists. The documentation does show examples of using Authorize, but I'm not seeing anything that lets me check for a permission against a resource.

Has the paradigm changed or is there another way to get this type of check done with ID4?

Comment: I think Scopes are your friends in IdentityServer 4.
A good way to handle authorization in .net core controllers with idsrv4 is providing policies saying which scopes are required for that policy and then apply those policies to the controller/controller methods with the authorize attribute.

Answer (score 2):

*You can add policies:*

**Startup.cs**

```
    services.AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions =>
        {
            authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(
                "SomePolicy",
                policyBuilder =>
                {
                    policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policyBuilder.AddRequirements(
                            new SomePolicyRequirement());
                });

        });
```

**SomePolicyRequirement.cs**

```
public class SomePolicyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public SomePolicyRequirement()
    {

    }
}
```

**SomePolicyHandler.cs**

```
public class SomePolicyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SomePolicyRequirement>
{
    public SomePolicyHandler()
    {

    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SomePolicyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var endpoint = context.Resource as Endpoint;
        if (endpoint == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        /*
        //RouteData can be controller, action or id
        var imageId = filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();

        if (!Guid.TryParse(imageId, out Guid imageIdAsGuid))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }*/

        /*
        //Repository check can go here
        var ownerId = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;

        if (!_someRepository.IsImageOwner(imageIdAsGuid, ownerId))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }*/

        // all checks out
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet core added some great features for authorization. Resource base authorization can implemented very easy with policy based authorization.

[Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1)